# Why does using `g_application_run` create a lag of ~25 seconds?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, lag

I'm trying to learn GTK3, but the documentation is problematic at best.  The most frustrating problem comes from using `g_application_run`.  It seems to create a lag of ~25 seconds when the program is run.

Here is the example:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget *window;

    window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 200);
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkApplication *app;

    app = gtk_application_new("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activate), NULL);
    g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref(app);

    return 0;
}
```

Very minimal, it creates a window, shows it and exits.  Basically testing the time to load.  When run with `time` I get the following results:

```
$ time ./capplication_new 

real    0m25.177s
user    0m0.151s
sys     0m0.014s
```

Over 25 seconds for the program to run.  This is really unacceptable.  What is most frustrating about this is that it's the newest code you're supposed to start using.  But if I run this minimal example of creating a window, showing it and exiting:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 300, 200);
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_widget_show(window);

exit(0);

    gtk_main();
}
```

When run with `time`, the results are:

```
$ time ./binit 

real    0m0.139s
user    0m0.108s
sys     0m0.023s
```

Is there a way to stop it from lagging?  Why is it lagging?  Why is this the new code if it lags?

**EDIT:

```
$ uname -a
Linux testing 5.10.0-11-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.92-1 (2022-01-18) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Which operation/line takes up the time'

Comment: 'gtk_main();' what is the point of that call?

Comment: @MartinJames  I've found the lag to be the command `g_application_run`.  If I add `exit(0);` to the start of the `activate()` function, the lag still exists.  So I imagine it has to do with what `g_application_run` does before it calls `activate()`

Comment: @MartinJames `gtk_main()` is the loop that monitors events.  I added the `exit` before it, to show the loading takes so long.  Removing the `exit` doesn't add any lag.

Comment: Such latency issues may come from the antivirus. You could make a test by temporary disabling it.

Comment: @Damien First, there is no antivirus running at all.  Second, if it was the antivirus, why would the second method work and not the first?

Comment: I tried reproducing this in C, and my times are `real: 0m0.098s`, `user: 0m0.064s`, and `sys: 0m0.020s` (for your first program). I tried reproducing this in Python, and my times are: `real: 0m0.248s`, `user: 0m0.196s`, and `sys: 0m0.033s`. Basically, no lag whatsoever. I'm on Ubuntu, but my computer isn't high-end or anything. What system are you on? Have you tried restarting your computer (just trying to eliminate possibilities)?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin Reboot didn't help.  My post has been edited to include my os.

Comment: Could be an X [session problem](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=239331)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find out why it was happening, but I was able to find a solution.

You need to add the following to your `.xinitrc` or `.xsession` file:

```
dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS DISPLAY XAUTHORITY
```

Answer (score 0):

To find out why it is lagging on your machine and not on other peoples' machines you will need to do some more debugging. I suggest starting with `ltrace` (which you may need to install). You can run:

```
ltrace -t -f -e '@*' ./capplication_new
```

That should show you all the library calls being made inside your application and help highlight the ones causing the delay.

From your timings we can see that your app is spending almost all of the 25 seconds doing nothing but waiting on something else. Hopefully the `ltrace` will help determine what that is. When we know that, we can work out how to fix it.